# How to hide a div when I click outside of it

Tags: html, css, jquery

Tough this issue is similar to many others I found here,I cannot find a proper answer that can work to me.

All of my content is loaded using .ajax() method, and events are handled using .on().
First I've tried to stop the propagation of the function using .stopPropagation(),it works in a way.Its closing the div,but after that any element I press it still using the closing function.I've found out by searching on the web that I need to use .off() method.

Here is the code(made it shorter):

```
$("#pnNotaCom").on("click",function(){
   $(".cautareProdNouNC").css({"display":"block"});
    $("html").on("click",function(){
        $(".cautareProdNouNC").css("display","none");
    });
});

$(".cautareProdNouNC").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$("#pnNotaCom").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

The div I am showing/hiding is `.cautareProdNouNC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it. When you activate your div, you activate invisible div that fulfills whole body. Clicking on that div hides them both.

HTML

```
<div class="cautareProdNouNC display_none"></div>
<div class="overlay display_none"></div><!--place it in body-->
```

CSS

```
.cautareProdNouNC {
    position relative; /*this div needs to be above overlay so needs z-index*/
    z-index: 200;
}
.display_none {
    display: none;
}
.overlay {
    background: transparent;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

jquery

```
$("#pnNotaCom").on("click",function(){
$(".cautareProdNouNC").removeClass('display_none');
$(".overlay").removeClass('display_none');
});

$(".overlay").on("click",function(){
$(this).addClass('display_none');
$(".cautareProdNouNC").addClass('display_none');
}
```

Comment: Your answer is not bad,I will give it a try,tough .cautareProdNouNC is  positioned as absolute.I will let you know how it worked

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's relative or absolute, it just needs some position specified for z-index to work. Hope it works.

Comment: Thank you, it worked,but I didn't used classes, just used .css() to display:block and display:none;

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).delegate('click', function(){
    if($('#Div2Hide').get(0) != $(this).get(0)){ 
        $('#Div2Hide').hide();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Comment: I will try.But don't know if I will be able to.I will let you know

Comment: Sorry I cannot provide a fiddle that would be almost the same with my code so it would show the issues.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
var container = $(your hiding div selector here);

if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
&&
container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
{
    container.hide();
}
});
```

Comment: It's working 99%.I have problems adding a ajax request after the div hides,can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question right!

What about this [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/IZAZaWA/2/edit):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var div_hide = false;

$("#one").on("click",function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("You click the div");      

    $(document).on("click",function(){

        if (div_hide === false) { // You can click once after that 
                                  // we set "div_hide" to "true"

               $(".hide_me").hide();
               div_hide = true;              
        }

      return false;

    });
  });
});
```